# How to access files stored in one ubuntu account from another?

Tags: networking

The Scenario is there are 5 computers and 5 users are connected . Each user has been given option to set his Ubuntu account detail (ie Ubuntu account username & Password) and once that is done , we can access our account from any of the computers . Now if i have password of 2 different accounts , how can i transfer a file between two Ubuntu accounts without using any external storage device or net ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't copy files between two computers without using a network or storage device. This has no sense, you need a transfer media....

To use a network:

you have to use [scp](http://linux.die.net/man/1/scp).

scp copies files between hosts on a network. It uses ssh for data transfer, and uses the same authentication and provides the same security as ssh.

Copy the file "textfile.txt" from a computer 2 to the local host

```
scp user2@computer2:textfile.txt /some/local/directory
```

To copy a folder "foo" from  the local host to cpmputer2

```
scp -r foo user2@computer2 /some/directory/computer2
```

### [More scp examples](http://www.hypexr.org/linux_scp_help.php)

***PS:*** The command cp is used in the same computer for two different users and this is not the case in the question

Comment: @Kamiko Ho or you can use nautilus for this

Answer (score 1):

> how can i transfer a file between two Ubuntu accounts without using
>   any external storage device or net

First need to create directory for files:

`mkdir ~/user2files`

User with admin privileges need to add permission for user2's group:

`sudo chgrp -R /home/user1/user2files`

Copy files to created directory:

`su user2 -c 'cp /home/user2/file /home/user1/user2files/'`

---

Or simply add all users to one group:

```
sudo groupadd allusers
sudo gpasswd -M user1,user2,user3 allusers
```

and apply group permissions to /home dir:

`sudo chgrp -R allusers /home`

Comment: Thankyou that was helpful and can we do this task without having admin privledge ?

Comment: you can't use cp between two different computers

Comment: @NewUSer _without using any external storage device or net_

Comment: @KamikoHo you can use  New USer's solution for local files. You just need to install `ssh` package. After installing `gvfs-backends package` you can use sftp:/user2@localhost/ in Nautilus.

Comment: @imraro you can't copy files between two different computers without using a transfer media. This has no sense

Comment: @NewUSer _how can i transfer a file between two Ubuntu **accounts**_  not computers.

Comment: @imraro your solution is perfect for using between two accounts. But the OP is asking about two accounts in two differenet computers not on local machine

Comment: @NewUSer User Yes i meant two different computers !